how to run multiple users in consecutive order under one thread group using jmeter?
i have a http post request. i have 4 users and 30 data sets of data in a csv file. now the 1st user should run the request for 6 times using the first 6 data sets from csv file. after the 1st user has completed running then the 2nd user will up and run the request for 5 times using the data from the 7th line from csv file. after completion the 3rd user will up and run the test for 10 times using the data from 11th line in the csv file. after completion the 4th user will up and run the request for 9 times using the data from 21th line in the csv file. here there is a catch if the 1st user  is running then the remaining users shouldn't perform any test. that means only one user should run at a time. the csv file looks like this
 1,9223372036854648323,1
1,9223372036854648342,2
1,9223372036854648351,3
1,9223372036854648378,4
1,9223372036854648401,5
1,9223372036854648404,6
2,9223372036854648444,7
2,9223372036854648461,8
2,9223372036854648468,9
2,9223372036854648479,10
2,9223372036854648515,11
3,9223372036854648523,12
3,9223372036854648543,13
3,9223372036854648573,14
3,9223372036854648576,15
3,9223372036854648621,16
3,9223372036854648632,17
3,9223372036854648648,18
3,9223372036854648649,19
3,9223372036854648671,20
3,9223372036854648672,21
4,9223372036854648676,22
4,123,23
4,9223372036854648686,24
4,9223372036854648691,25
4,9223372036854648693,26
4,9223372036854648694,27
4,9223372036854648698,28
4,9223372036854648701,29
4,9223372036854648703,30

thanks in advance for the help. can anyone help me to run in the above mentioned way?
